# Upstart program does not start on startup, starts on command normally - no logs produced

Tags: python, upstart

I'm trying to run a super simple Upstart script in Ubuntu to run a python program as a daemon and for the life of me can't figure out why it's failing. I put this in my /etc/init/ directory named as program.conf.

```
description "Program Startup"
author      "Team X"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /home/punk/dev/workspace/program/ui/
exec /usr/bin/python /home/punk/dev/workspace/program/ui/server.py
respawn
```

The program does not start on startup and I see absolutely no logs in /var/log/program.log (it's empty). I'm trying to make it start when the lo interface runs (the program is a web server that binds to localhost) Running initctl reload-configuration goes fine, and I can see the program when I run sudo initctl list:

```
punk@punk-VirtualBox:/var/log/upstart$ sudo initctl list | grep program
program stop/waiting
```

Running this starts the program as expected every time and produces logging output to the expected file:

```
punk@punk-VirtualBox:/var/log/upstart$ sudo start program
program start/running, process 3161
```

Am I making any obvious mistakes here? Since there's no output to the logs I'm totally baffled on where to go from here, any suggestions? I suspect there's an issue with the "start on" line, but damned if I know what it is...

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Comment: I had the same problem trying to start a script after files and network were started. start on runlevel [2345] worked fine. Why I don't know.

Comment: Do you have a network mounted /usr? Take a look in kern.log to see if Upstart had anything to say about the job.

Comment: @AndersBornholm yeah, I actually tried that as well with absolutely no change in the outcome and no logs to show anything. Eventually I just copied cron's upstart script and edited a single line starting my program - still didn't work with no logs. I spent all day trying to get this simple thing to work and finally gave up. I deployed my app through Apache and was done with it.